# What exactly happens when finish() is called on a non-top activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Suppose we somehow have a reference to an activity not on the top of activity stack. Can we call `finish()` on this activity, and what exactly will happen in such a case?

Also, what would be legitimate reason to hold on a reference to a non-top activity? Saving the reference in some static field is a way to have access to non-top activities but it is against best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can call `finish()` on this activity. There is no difference between fore ground and background Activities.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intent); // Now this Activity goes to background

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finish", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish(); // Finished as normal.
    }
}, 2000);
```

Avoid holding a reference of an activity to a static filed. It will lead to memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

> finish() on this activity, and what exactly will happen in such a
>   case?

I'm sure you can. You will just end up with a black screen for the non-top activity if it is still visible on screen.

> Also, what would be legitimate reason to hold on a reference to a
>   non-top activity?

I think you would have to consider whether your design is correct if you have to keep a reference to an activity that is currently in the background. This will lead to a lot of memory leaks if you keep old activity hanging around as the GC cannot collect.

> Saving the reference in some static field is a way to have access to
>   non-top activities

You should use a class like Constants.java to put in all your static fields from your non-top activity and reuse the values from Constants.java.